# Parsing name value pairs from long string using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

Regular expressions are a sure way to bring me back to earth. I don't think I've ever produced one without help, so here is another cry for help. Here's the example input:

> {{Taxobox | name = Impala | status = LC | status_system = IUCN3.1 |
>   status_ref = {{IUCN2008|assessors=IUCN SSC Antelope
>   Specialist Group |year=2008|id=550|title=Aepyceros
>   melampus|downloaded=18 January 2009}} Database entry includes a brief
>   justification of why this species is of least concern | trend =
>   stable | image = Serengeti Impala3.jpg | image_caption= Young male
>   Impala in [[Serengeti]], [[Tanzania]] | image2=Female_impala.jpg |
>   image2_caption= Female Impala in [[Mikumi National Park]],
>   [[Tanzania]] | regnum = [[Animal]]ia | phylum = [[Chordate|Chordata]]
>   | classis = [[Mammal]]ia | ordo = [[Even-toed ungulate|Artiodactyla]]
>   | familia = [[Bovid]]ae | subfamilia = '''Aepycerotinae''' |
>   subfamilia_authority = [[John Edward Gray|Gray]], 1872 | genus =
>   '''''Aepyceros''''' | genus_authority = [[Carl Jakob
>   Sundevall|Sundevall]], 1847 | species = '''''A. melampus''''' |
>   subdivision_ranks = Subspecies | subdivision = * ''[[Aepyceros
>   melampus petersi|A. m. petersi]]''
>   * ''A. m. melampus'' | range_map=Leefgebied_impala.JPG | range_map_caption=Range map | binomial = ''Aepyceros melampus'' |
>   binomial_authority = ([[Martin Lichtenstein|Lichtenstein]], 1812) |
>   range_map = Impala.png | range_map_caption = Distribution of the
>   Impala 
>  Red =A. m. melampus 
>  Blue =  A. m. petersi }}

Sorry I can't get this formatted in a better way. It's a long string with no newlines in them. It is essentially a set of name-value pairs. Each pair the format:

**pipe space attributename space equals space attributevalue space**

There's no obvious end character to a pair, other than the pipe of the next pair.

What I'd like to do is to turn this into an associative array in PHP. For what it's worth, here's my attempt of at least trying to find some matches:

```
$pattern = "/\|([^=|^.]*)=([^\|]*)|/s";
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $pagecontent, $matches)) {
var_dump($matches);
} else echo "no match!";
```

It's way of so don't pay too much attention to it. I'm hoping for some regex masters to help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to isolate the contained string from the `{{` and `}}` delimiters before you try to extract the pairs. This will fail on your example due to what looks like nested grouping with `status_ref={{...}}`. You will need preg_replace_callback and a `(?R)` pattern for that.

A regex like this might work for the pairs itself however:

```
"/(?<=  ^ | \|)  # start, of string, or after any |
  \s*(\w+)       # name
  (?:\s*=\s*(    #  =
  \{\{.*?\}\}    # {{....}}
  | \[\[.*?\]\]  # [[...]]
  | \(.*?\)      # (...)
  | [^|]+) )?    # plain values
 /sx"
```

It will give you an associative array with:

```
$array = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

With the lonely name tokens not getting an associated value of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't fully understand how to put together all the extra hints though. Running your pattern as-is leads to some pairs but also a lot of names with empty value strings, as well as values endind up on the "names" side. Are you saying the callback provides a solution for that? How?

Comment: Would it help if I'd say that I do not need to preserve nesting? I'm looking for a flat name-value pair array. it's also ok if the values would contain curly braces, but preferably not.

Comment: On second look your input has a more complex grammar. It can be done with the callback or ?R approach, but that's too complex to you, too much effort for me. You can add more exceptions as shown in the edit, then manually traverse entries to split up as well. But that's all I can help here.

Comment: Your second example brings me a lot closer to my goal, at like 90%. I can probably post-process the rest myself. Although I'd prefer a 100% regex matcher for the sake of elegance this definitely was helpful. I'll wait for the rest of the evening to see if someone gives another shot a new pattern, if not, yours is the accepted answer. Thanks!